# How to calculate area using the V-Q Lissajous method

Tags: high-voltage, power-dissipation, lissajous-figure

[image]

I am doing research on carbon conversion using the high voltage plasma method. In my research there is one problem, namely calculating the dissipation power where one of the parameters is determining the area of the Lissajous diagram
I don't know how to calculate the area of a Lissajous diagram and whether this area is suitable for use in formulas

```
Pi=mSFC0
m is the raiso of the voltage divider
s is the area of the Lissajous area
f is frequency
C0 is the capacitor used
```

Comment: What kind of accuracy do you need on the area calculation?

Comment: Calculate as this : https://circuitglobe.com/what-is-hysteresis-loss.html#:~:text=Definition%3A%20The%20work%20done%20by,hysteresis%20is%20called%20Hysteresis%20Loss.

Answer (score 0):

One way to calculate the area is to just estimate the number of squares of the inside area of the loop. If that doesn't work you'll need an algorithm to calculate the area parametrically.

One way you could do this with the data is use a convex hull library to find if the points are inside or outside of the convex hull. Because the data is noisy not all points will be inside the hull. The convex hull would give a good approximation to the area inside the hull. Once you found that you could find the area of the convex hull.

Comment: Thank you for the advice
I thought of one method which is to print a lissajous diagram image on hvs paper and compare the weight of the whole area with the weight of a 1cm^2 square, do you think this method makes sense?
and later the unit of area obtained is cm^2. Can this be used in the power dissipation formula above

Answer (score 0):

If you have a closed curve that you want to find the area of, and you know sufficiently many points on the curve for a good estimate, [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem?useskin=vector) is exactly what you want. You may have to fudge the numbers a bit as your curve isn't completely closed.

The statement of the theorem most useful for your case is this:
$$A=\oint_C x\ dy,$$

where A is the area you want, x and y are the cartesian coordinates (here, those are V and Q), and the integral is taken counterclockwise around the curve.

Rewriting it using your variables:
$$S=\oint_C V\ dQ.$$

Or, if it happens to be an easier integral to take,
$$S=-\oint_C Q\ dV.$$

As your curve is measured and you have only numerical data (so a symbolic integration isn't possible), you can approximate this integral by whatever approximation method you prefer--trapezoidal is probably good enough.